# Trying to verify password via JSONarray in android

Tags: java, android, json, getjson, arrays

It's been too long since I last attempted an application and for the life of me, I can't seem to get an answer myself. I need to get a user to enter a password and username in my application upon login, and I wat to do that by searching a database in PHP Myadmin.

I've got the code to a level where (I think) it should be close to completion, but the logic escapes me.

I need to figure the if statement to compare the username and password the user entered to the database via the JSONArray, also, if the code won't work anyway, a heads up will be appreciated :)

if statement is marked with ----> I know I need some form of for loop to siv through and compare values, but it's something i've never dealt with.

Here's the code for my login screen:

```
    public class HomeScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private ProgressDialog m_ProgressDialog = null;


    EditText editText1;
    EditText editText2;
    String clear1;
    String user;
    String password;
    URL url;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

        View loginBTN = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        loginBTN.setOnClickListener(this);

        editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        clear1 ="";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:

                user = editText1.getText().toString();
                password = editText2.getText().toString();

                if  ( editText1 != null && editText1.length() != 0 && editText2 != null && editText2.length() != 0){    
                    getData();
                    m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(HomeScreen.this,    
                              "Please wait...", "Checking Details...", true);
                        m_ProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);

                     if(testData()) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(this, Afterlog.class);
                        startActivity(i);       
                    }

                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(HomeScreen.this, "The username and password did not match any in our database...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(HomeScreen.this, "Please enter a user name AND a password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;

}
}


private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
        }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static JSONArray readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
try {
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
  String jsonText = readAll(rd);
  JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonText);
  return json;
} finally {
  is.close();
}
}

    public void getData() {

    try{

        json = readJsonFromUrl("http://localhost/indextest.php?function=getdata");

        Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("BACKGROUND_PROC", e.getMessage());
      }


}

public boolean testData() {
    getData();
    user = editText1.getText().toString();
    password = editText2.getText().toString();  

    for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject currentObject = json.getJSONObject(i);
        if (currentObject.getString("username", "").equals(user) && currentObject.getString("password", "").equals(password))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I gave you an answer on your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066237/comparing-values-from-textviews-and-jsonarray) please get back to me

Answer (score 1):

You want to authenticate the user? If it is that so, then I don't think this is the right approach. You should send username and password to the server (encripted maybe) and then the server would check if the username and password match and would reply you a simple JSON like:

```
{
     response: 1
}
```

indicating that the authentication was successful (0 otherwise, for example).

If you just want to get data from a JSON Object than I would suggest to change your `JSONArrayObject` for a JSONObject and to retrieve data from it you can just do:

```
JSONObject json = getData(); // getData now returns a JSONObject
String username = json.getString ("username");
```

I'm supposing a JSON like:

```
{
    username: "Foo",
    password: "123"
}
```

**//// EDIT --------------------------------**

You can have your getDate function checking if it already matches and returning true or false if it does so. Like this:

```
public boolean getDate() {
     // Get your data and put it into a JSONArray

     for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
         JSONObject currentObject = json.getJSONObject(i);
         if (currentObject.getString("username").equals(user) && currentObject.getString("password").equals(password))
             return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

Your JSON HAVE to be something like:

```
 [
     {
         username: "Foo1",
         password: "123"
     },
     {
         usernmae: "Foo2",
         password: "123"
     }, ...
 ]
```

Then your if would be just:

```
if(getData()) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Afterlog.class);
    startActivity(i);       
}
```

Comment: Figured that would be the solution too, but with my zero skillset it's sort of an example app that i'm just playing around with, so the whole table will contain like two or three names, just to show functionality. :)

Comment: Ok, so you will retrieve your whole table (2 or 3 users) to the app and then check if some of them match. Is it?

Comment: Correct, just loop the array or some sort, I figured I could do that in the getData() function and then just return a value if it matches that I can check with the if?

Comment: That looks like it should work, the only problem is I get an error with the getString(String) functions. And I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - The method getString(String) in the type JSONObject is not applicable for the arguments 
  (String, String)
 - The method getString(String) in the type JSONObject is not applicable for the arguments 
  (String, String)

Comment: My god, my bad... It shouldnt have the second string parameter... I edited it... Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

You should only be sending the username and password to the API. The API will then check the database and then it should return a status to the client application - success or failure.

It is not good practice to send sensitive information (like a password) back to the client application and then loop through values to do the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Found a very simple and to the point tutorial here:

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/22/create-simple-login-form-php-android-connect-php-android/